# How to use a list of label names for starting threads

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, sbcl

I want to use a list of label-names to define the order/amount of threads started with those functions. But it does not work as SBCL complains:

> DO-STUFF isn't fbound.

E.g:

```
(labels ((do-stuff (argI argII) (values argI argII))
         (do-stuff-II (argI argII) (values argII argI)))
  (mapcar #'(lambda(name)
              (sb-thread:make-thread name :arguments '(1 2)))
          '(do-stuff do-stuff-II do-stuff)))
```

Using a macro which expands the list into:

```
(labels ((do-stuff (argI argII) (values argI argII))
         (do-stuff-II (argI argII) (values argII argI)))
  (let ((threads nil))
    (push (sb-thread:make-thread #'do-stuff :arguments '(1 2)) threads)
    (push (sb-thread:make-thread #'do-stuff-II :arguments '(1 2)) threads)
    (push (sb-thread:make-thread #'do-stuff :arguments '(1 2)) threads)
    threads))
```

works, but this strikes me as not as elegant due to the use of unnecessary let and push.

**How can I fix my first approach? Do I have to write a macro?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have access to SBCL at the moment to test it, but the problem seems to be that you're not passing functions to MAKE-THREAD, you're passing symbols.

Replace this:

```
'(do-stuff do-stuff-II do-stuff)
```

With this:

```
(list #'do-stuff #'do-stuff-II #'do-stuff)
```

And it should work.

Comment: The standard dispatch macro-character sequence `#'` is equivalent to writing a `function` form, as in `#'foo` === `(function foo)`. If you quote the `(function foo)` form, it won't be processed. The closest thing you could to is `\`(,#'do-stuff ,#'do-stuff-II ,#'do-stuff)`, but this is just about the same as the `list` expression.